# Do any non-trivial equations hold between interior operators and closure operators on a topological space?

Tags: general-topology

Fix a topological space $X$, and write $\iota$ and $\kappa$ for (respectively) the interior and closure operators associated with $X$. Hence $\{\iota,\kappa\}$ is a subset of the monoid of endofunctions of the powerset of $X$. Let $M_X$ denote the submonoid generated by this subset.

> **Question.** Do any non-trivial equations (i.e. equations other than $\iota^2=\iota$ and $\kappa^2=\kappa$ and those that can be proved from these two starting points using the monoid axioms) necessarily hold in the monoid $M_X$?

*Edit.* So far its been stated that $(\kappa \iota)^2 = \kappa \iota$ and $(\iota \kappa)^2= \iota \kappa$ hold. I'd like to know if these equations are complete for the class of monoids that can be expressed in the form $M_X$ (with respect to the inference methods of equational logic).

If not, what further axioms do we need?

Comment: Is $(\kappa\iota)^2=\kappa\iota$ nontrivial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kuratowski's closure-complement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_closure-complement_problem) may gives an answer of your question. First note that $c\kappa c = \iota$, where $c$ is the complement operator. Kuratowski's theorem gives following equation:

$$(\kappa \iota)^2 = \kappa\iota.$$

Comment: Does $(\iota \kappa)^2 = \iota \kappa$? Also, I don't get the relevance of Kuratowski's theorem, assuming you mean [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski's_theorem).

Comment: @goblin Yes, since $\iota\kappa\iota\kappa = c(\kappa c\kappa c\kappa c\kappa c)c = c(\kappa c\kappa c)c = \iota\kappa$. I made a mistake in my answer :( .

Comment: @goblin Kuratowski's theorem I mentioned is [his closure-complement theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski%27s_closure-complement_problem). I linked it on the first word in my answer.

Comment: haha, right. $\;\!$